# PC Stalls trying to open Downloads location

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer

I noticed this a few times... it can take 10-20s for my Win10 PC to open the downloads location from File Explorer. But other folders/drives open instantly as you'd expect.

I don't recall downloads being a special location - it's just a regular folder not a virtual location or anything, right?

What might cause this to occur?

Comment: please tell us if my proposed answer worked for you. If so, please mark it as anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known 'issue', a Google research returns a lot of articles explaining how to get rid of this annoying behaviour.

To summarize :

**Cause :** Your Download folder might be optimized for **Pictures items**. Therefore, it tries to load thumbnails, which takes some time (rendering or so).

**Solution :** Configure your Download folder to be optimized for **General items**.

**Source :** http://www.istartedsomething.com/20121202/quick-fix-for-very-slow-to-load-downloads-folder-in-windows-7-8/

*Excerpt of the source article :*

> For some reason, the “Downloads” folder likes to be categorized as a
>   “Pictures” folder (I’m guessing because people store a lot of JPGs in
>   it). The problem with this view is that it tries to generate
>   thumbnails for all the files in this folder, even if they’re not
>   pictures.
>
> The fix is to ensure the folder settings for “Downloads” is optimized
>   for “General items”. This should have an instant effect (the next time
>   you add files to the folder since the thumbnails are otherwise cached
>   anyway).

Comment: Just because it wasn't 100% obvious to me. To change this setting, **right click on the folder, go to properties, customise, then change the Optimise drop down to "General items"**.